# not able to restart SharePoint Timer Service (SPTimerV4)

Tags: 2013, 2010

I tried

```
net stop SPTimerV4
net start SPTimerV4
```

It says service is already stopping or starting

I also tried **task manager** and status of **SPTimerV4** says its "stopping", I am not able to right click and start it there as well

What can be done other than a server restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an IISreset first then restart SharePoint Administrative services. Wait for some time. about 15 mins you restart. Then try to refresh the timer job and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

In the details view of Task Manager, find OWSTIMER.EXE and End task.